# SpriteKit: Determining the strength of a collision

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Using SpriteKit, is there a simple way to determine how *strong* a particular collision between two `physicsBody`'s is?

Here's what I mean by "strong": a direct hit should be "stronger" than a glancing blow.

I'm not sure where to start, so any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do this, but how about comparing the kinetic energy of each body before and after the collision?

Comment: `SKPhysicsContact` has a `collisionImpulse` field: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicscontact/1478523-collisionimpulse

Comment: @bg2b That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Doh! I can think of several reasons why you'd want to do this! :-)

Comment: @bg2b Interesting - thanks. So this is a property of the SKPhysicsContact object, so that implies that you need to have contacts enabled for the objects you wish to examine. If you have contacts but not collisions enabled, does this still get populated (perhaps with the strength of the collision that would have occurred had they been enabled)?

Comment: I never used the field myself so I'm not sure, but I'd guess it would be populated regardless since the documentation doesn't discuss any limitations on the fields related to the collision.